# jwt-signature: Unable to load and verify the token

Tags: php, laravel, jwt, amazon-cognito

I have a Laravel based API that uses AWS Cognito's ID tokens for authentication. Using `Authorization: Bearer ...` header I am parsing the AWS Cognito ID Token on each request to obtain the email address from the token. I borrowed the concept from this `TokenParser` class: https://github.com/cgauge/laravel-cognito-provider/blob/master/src/TokenParser.php.

I recently upgraded my dev environment from L8 (php 7.4) to L9 (php 8.2) and it no longer works. The error message is thrown by the `jwt-signature` package in function `loadAndVerifyWithKeySet` (`JWSLoader` class) and it states:

"Unable to load and verify the token."

Nothing has changed just the environment and Laravel version. Can someone help me resolve this?

Comment: It turns out I had outdated jwt-framework. I upgraded the package to ^3.0 and tokens validate properly but now it takes like 19 seconds to verify the token. Why is it so slow?

Comment: Having the same performance bottleneck. Have you found a solution?

Comment: Yes, as it turned out I was missing bcmath / gmp extensions. Please see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75976047/web-token-jwt-signature-algorithm-rsa-rs-256-algorithm-slowness