# web-token/jwt-signature-algorithm-rsa - RS 256 algorithm - slowness

Tags: php, jwt, rsa

I have a `TokenParser` class that looks like this:

https://github.com/cgauge/laravel-cognito-provider/blob/master/src/TokenParser.php

My app runs perfectly with L8 (php 7.4) but after upgrading to L9 LTS (php 8.2), the `loadAndVerifyWithKeySet()` function executes for around 19 seconds. After some digging there's a signature algorithm verification function that's causing the slowness:

```
// file: jwt-signature-algorithm-rsa/RSAPKCS1.php
public function verify(JWK $key, string $input, string $signature): bool
    {
        $this->checkKey($key);
        $pub = RSAKey::createFromJWK($key->toPublic()); // Causes slowness

        return openssl_verify($input, $signature, $pub->toPEM(), $this->getAlgorithm()) === 1;
    }
```

Can someone help me fix this? What could be causing the slowness in parsing the token?

Answer (score 2):

Florent Morselli helped me with this issue:

"When RSA-based cipher operations are slow, this means it uses PHP classes instead of GMP or BCMATH extension."

I installed GMP extension on PHP 8.2 (Ubuntu)